# Trouble with ajax script using onClick to submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have several forms on a page that submit values from radio buttons using jquery/ajax.  All works fine when a Submit button is used, but I would like to eliminate the Submit button.  I tried using onClick to submit.  However, trying it this way causes the forms to get submitted prior to the processing script picking them up.  I would very much appreciate advice (and example if possible).  Thank you, Brian

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// process the form
$('form').submit(function(event) {


    // get the form data
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        :  formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json' // what type of data do we expect back from the server


    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

        if (data.success) {
            // success.
            // hide form container          
            $("#"+data.message).hide();
            $("#"+data.message+"hr").hide();
        }

            // log data to the console so we can see
            //console.log(data); 

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

Form:

```
<method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="yes" onClick="onClick="this.form.submit()">
```

Comment: When do you want to submit the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for onclick is wrong, but putting onclick attributes on elements is an outdated way of doing things in any case.

You probably want to handle the `change` event rather than `click`, since the selection of the radiobutton happens after the click, so if you submit the form right away the radiobutton might not be selected yet (I'm not sure, I'd have to experiment, but `change` is probably more foolproof).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(event) {
        //the rest of your code goes here
        //you don't need event.preventDefault() anymore
    });
});
```

Edit: `$(this)` won't refer to the form anymore of course, just replacing it with `$('form')` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the suggestion and am implementing it.  Unfortunately, $('form') doesn't seem to work.  Do I need to get the form name somehow?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? What's happening? $('form') should be pretty foolproof, I suspect you're getting Javascript errors. Do you know how to use a developer console?

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity.  The problem is that this page dynamically displays multiple forms (each with a unique id), and I was serializing the selected values with `formData = $(this).serialize();` which is then handled asynchronously by a php script. Unfortunately, `$('form')` takes the values from all the forms rather than just the one from which the change event occurred. I do have the console.  Thanks.

Comment: One last question...I have the form's id in the variable formID but now having trouble with the syntax to reference it.  Could you please steer me to the correct syntax. Using `var formData = document.forms[formID].serialize();` results in "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".  I'm learning javascript and arrived at this syntax from the documentation, but I must be missing something.  Thank you.

Comment: That isn't working because that's pure javascript and you need a jQuery object to call `serialize` on. You want `$('#form_id_here')`.